# Countdown timer with Pause/Resume Start/Stop function

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I am creating my function where I can manage pause and resume and reset the countdown.
I have read various threads but I don't know how I merge that code with my own function.
basically I am doing countdown, my default countdown is 15sec once I click <kbd>start</kbd> button that counter will start `15,14,13...` in this between If I click <kbd>pause</kbd> the counter will pause and same will resume on click <kbd>resume</kbd> and finally the time will reset as 15 sec on click <kbd>reset</kbd>
Please help, I create my own function with wonderful UI, how I add this above, pause, resume, reset function in my code.

```js
// Credit: Mateusz Rybczonec

const FULL_DASH_ARRAY = 283;
const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

const COLOR_CODES = {
  info: {
    color: "green"
  },
  warning: {
    color: "orange",
    threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD
  },
  alert: {
    color: "red",
    threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD
  }
};

const TIME_LIMIT = 15;
let timePassed = 0;
let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
let timerInterval = null;
let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div class="base-timer">
  <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="base-timer__circle">
      <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
      <path
        id="base-timer-path-remaining"
        stroke-dasharray="283"
        class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
        d="
          M 50, 50
          m -45, 0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
        "
      ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
    timeLeft
  )}</span>
</div>
`;

function onTimesUp() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
}

function startTimer() {
  timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timePassed = timePassed += 1;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
      timeLeft
    );
    setCircleDasharray();
    setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      onTimesUp();
      alert("Time Up");
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
  const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
  if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(warning.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(alert.color);
  } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(info.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(warning.color);
  }
}

function calculateTimeFraction() {
  const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
  return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
}

function setCircleDasharray() {
  const circleDasharray = `${(
    calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY
  ).toFixed(0)} 283`;
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
}

function starTimer(){
    startTimer();
}

function pauseTimer(){
    //pause timer
}
function resumeTimer(){
    //resume timer
}
function resetTimer(){
    //reset time to 15sec by default;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  place-items: center;
}

.base-timer {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.base-timer__svg {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.base-timer__circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}

.base-timer__path-elapsed {
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke: grey;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining {
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 1s linear all;
  fill-rule: nonzero;
  stroke: currentColor;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.green {
  color: rgb(65, 184, 131);
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.orange {
  color: orange;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.red {
  color: red;
}

.base-timer__label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<input type="button" onclick="starTimer()" value="Start"/>
<input type="button" onclick="pauseTimer()" value="Pause"/>
<input type="button" onclick="resumeTimer()" value="Resume"/>
<input type="button" onclick="resetTimer()" value="Reset"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function onTimesUp() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
  timerInterval = undefined;
}
```

All you have to do is clear the interval and save the state for pausing the timer, and on resume let the start value be the previous stopped value.

In case of resume, it's same as the start function you've written.

For resetting, clear the timer and just set everything to your initial value.

```js
function starTimer() {
  if (!timerInterval) startTimer();
}


function pauseTimer() {
  onTimesUp();
}


function resumeTimer() {
  if (!timerInterval) startTimer();
}


function resetTimer() {
  if (timerInterval) {
    onTimesUp();
  }
  timePassed = 0;
  timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
  timerInterval = null;

  document.getElementById('base-timer-label').innerHTML = formatTime(timeLeft);
  setCircleDasharray();
  setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);
}
```

Here is a link to working [codepen](https://codepen.io/sarangnx/pen/jOZRwxO)

Answer (score 0):

To pause the timer, you need to clear the interval.
To resume, it is the same as starting.
To reset, you need to wrap the `document.getElementById("app").innerHTML =` with a named function, so you can call it again. See `init` below. Additionnally, you need to restore the initial variables.

```js
// Credit: Mateusz Rybczonec

const FULL_DASH_ARRAY = 283;
const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

const COLOR_CODES = {
  info: {
    color: "green"
  },
  warning: {
    color: "orange",
    threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD
  },
  alert: {
    color: "red",
    threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD
  }
};

let TIME_LIMIT = 15;
let timePassed = 0;
let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
let timerInterval = null;
let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;

function init() {
  document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
  <div class="base-timer">
    <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g class="base-timer__circle">
        <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
        <path
          id="base-timer-path-remaining"
          stroke-dasharray="283"
          class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
          d="
            M 50, 50
            m -45, 0
            a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
            a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
          "
        ></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
      timeLeft
    )}</span>
  </div>
  `;
}

function onTimesUp() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
  resetTimer();
}

function startTimer() {
  timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timePassed = timePassed += 1;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
      timeLeft
    );
    setCircleDasharray();
    setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      onTimesUp();
      alert("Time Up");
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
  const {
    alert,
    warning,
    info
  } = COLOR_CODES;
  if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(warning.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(alert.color);
  } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(info.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(warning.color);
  }
}

function calculateTimeFraction() {
  const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
  return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
}

function setCircleDasharray() {
  const circleDasharray = `${(
    calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY
  ).toFixed(0)} 283`;
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
}

function starTimer() {
  startTimer();
}

function pauseTimer() {
  //pause timer
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
}

function resumeTimer() {
  //resume timer
  startTimer();
}

function resetTimer() {
  TIME_LIMIT = 15;
  timePassed = 0;
  timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
  init();
}

// On page load
init();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  place-items: center;
}

.base-timer {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.base-timer__svg {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.base-timer__circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}

.base-timer__path-elapsed {
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke: grey;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining {
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 1s linear all;
  fill-rule: nonzero;
  stroke: currentColor;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.green {
  color: rgb(65, 184, 131);
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.orange {
  color: orange;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.red {
  color: red;
}

.base-timer__label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<input type="button" onclick="starTimer()" value="Start" />
<input type="button" onclick="pauseTimer()" value="Pause" />
<input type="button" onclick="resumeTimer()" value="Resume" />
<input type="button" onclick="resetTimer()" value="Reset" />
```

---

Your next task will be to reuse the buttons. So after on click on "Start", the button will turn to "Pause".  
Once paused, the button will be "Resume"... And will be "Start" after a "reset" click (which has to be another button).